# Python/Django Memcached keys expiration

Tags: django, python-2.7, memcached

I am using python/Django in my project with memcache. i just want to know what will happen if any of cache key get expired ? will the memory be free and ready to reuse?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Memcached's wiki article [NewUserInternals - No Guts No Glory](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewUserInternals#When_Memory_Is_Reclaimed). An item that expires will continue to set in memory until one of the following happens:

- Client will attempt to fetch expired data. Memcached will see that it's expired, reclaim the memory, and not return the value to the client.
- When a client request to store a new item, Memcached will check against Least Recently Used (LRU) for any expired items, and reclaim the memory.